# Query for below pattern in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to achieve the output shown at bottom, but do not get the idea how can it to be done.

`#T1` and `#T2` are the input tables.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(ID VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #T1
SELECT 'A'
UNION 
SELECT 'B'
UNION
SELECT 'C'
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE #T2
(ID VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #T2
SELECT 1
UNION 
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION 
SELECT 5
UNION
SELECT 6
UNION
SELECT 7
```

---

and the expected output by using the `#T1` and `#T2` is

```
OUTPUT 
ID ID
A  1
B  2
C  3
A  4
B  5
C  6
A  7
```

Comment: Is your output complete ? What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: impossible to answer because we do not know the logic that you used to create your output

Comment: As per T2 table T1 table's data will increment.. as it has only a,b,c so after after A,B,C it will start once from A like that

Comment: This looks like something that's a better fit for a *spreadsheet* rather than a relational database. Is there a specific reason you're doing this in SQL?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain your logic there, not in comments

Comment: but then T2 is useless, you just want to increment  records on T1?

Comment: @ThomasG - it's "take two sequences. Zip them together, reusing the shorter sequence repeatedly if necessary, to produce a result as long as the longer sequence"

Comment: that is the requirement.. @ThomasG

Answer (score 4):

It's not particularly pretty, however:

```
WITH T1 AS(
    SELECT ID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM #T1),
T1M AS(
    SELECT *, MAX(RN) OVER () AS MAXRN
    FROM T1),
T2 AS(
    SELECT ID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM #T2)

SELECT T1.ID AS T1ID,
       T2.ID AS T2ID
FROM T1M T1
     JOIN T2 ON T1.RN = CASE T2.RN % T1.MAXRN WHEN 0 THEN T1.MAXRN ELSE T2.RN % T1.MAXRN END
ORDER BY T2.ID ASC;
```

*Edit: note, this assumes that T1 has less rows than T2. if the inverse is true, this won't work.*

Comment: @AryanSena I wouldn't say the above is particular complex, it's just making use of `ROW_NUMBER()`, `MAX` and a `CASE` expression; just not pretty,

Comment: You can eliminate the `CASE` by doing `ON T1.RN % T1.MAXRN = T2.RN % T1.MAXRN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CTE`

```
with t1 as (
    select *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) Seq 
    from #t1
), t2 as (
    select *, 
           1+(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id)-1) % (select COUNT(1) from t1) Seq
    from #t2
) 
select t1.Id, t2.Id
from t2
inner join t1 on t1.Seq = t2.Seq
order by t2.Id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, it's bit longer process in the row numbering and grouping, but pretty much that's all the processes, putting on row number and grouping, pretty simple

```
with cte as (
    SELECT ID, ceiling(cast(row_number() over
    (order by ID ASC) as decimal)/ 3) as grp FROM #T2
)
SELECT T1.ID, T2.ID FROM 
(SELECT ID, cast(row_number() over
                   (order by ID ASC) as decimal) as grp FROM #T1) T1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, cast(row_number() over
                   (PARTITION BY grp order by ID ASC) as decimal) as grp FROM cte) T2
ON T1.grp = T2.grp
ORDER BY T2.ID
```

the result is as follows

[image]

Comment: Good concept - couple of modifications. Note that you can use % (modulo) instead of the ceiling/division logic. Also, the OP cannot necessarily hard-code a 3, which is why my solution counts the rows in T1.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03a3f/39

```
SELECT
  T1.ID
  , T2.ID
FROM
  (SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS ROW_NUM
   , T2.ID FROM T2
  ) AS T2
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS ROW_NUM
     , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1) AS SEQ_COUNT
     , T1.ID FROM T1
    ) AS T1 ON
      T1.ROW_NUM =
        CASE (T2.ROW_NUM % T1.SEQ_COUNT)
          WHEN 0 THEN T1.SEQ_COUNT
          ELSE (T2.ROW_NUM % T1.SEQ_COUNT)
        END
ORDER BY
  T2.ROW_NUM ASC;
```

Results:

```
+----+----+
| ID | ID |
+----+----+
| A  |  1 |
| B  |  2 |
| C  |  3 |
| A  |  4 |
| B  |  5 |
| C  |  6 |
| A  |  7 |
+----+----+
```